# How to assign Different type in single variable?

Tags: ios, swift, casting, type-conversion

I have three classes `firstVC`, `secondVC`, `finalVC`.
Now I am trying to create one variable in `finalVC`. Whose able take the value of both object class `firstVC` and `secondVC`  in single variable.

Below sample for that.

```
class finalVC: UIViewController{
    var objfinal: some-type!
    var objFirstVC: firstVC!
    Var objSecondVC: secondVC!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        objfinal = objFirstVC
        objfinal = objSecondVC
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var loginVc:LoginViewController?
var signupVc:SignUpViewController?
var objfinal: AnyObject?


override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

    objfinal = signupVc
    objfinal = loginVc

     objfinal = signupVc
    objfinal = loginVc

    if(objfinal is LoginViewController)
            {
                loginVc = objfinal as! LoginViewController
                print(loginVc.strName)
            }
            else if(objfinal is SignUpViewController)
            {
                 signupVc = objfinal as! SignUpViewController
    print(signupVc.strPicUrl)
            }

        }
```

Comment: using this i not able to access the variable of class file

Comment: Vinod kumar thank you for answer but thing i need to optimize my code.

Comment: Please check it  @Sakir Sherasiya

Comment: if i want access like `objfinal.strName` then